# Reseting variable after some time

Tags: flutter

I would like to reset a Map var, after two days. But not something like an await Duration, I want the user to still use the app, so maybe something like a timer.

Ex. If the user has liked some videos, the videos that he has liked won't be showed again as a suggestion until two days have passed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you need a timer for this. You just have to store the datetime when he liked the video. Then you can decide whether it should be shown or not on the suggestion, by checking current datetime and stored datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that using [Isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) in which you can put a [Timer.periodic](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html).
Since you are talking about days, the app will likely be closed in that amount of time so you should also periodically save and read back those vars on app startup from either [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) or a [file](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files). Also each time a user likes a video you should save both what the user liked and [when he liked it](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html).

Here is a pretty good [article](https://codingwithjoe.com/dart-fundamentals-isolates/) about Isolates and timers in dart, this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jebright/a7086adc305615aa3a655c6d8bd90264) has an example of it in Flutter.